# I am looking for a geolocation api to search location

Tags: location

I want to get all location within a particular radius distance. Which API should I use? I have the longitude and latitude of locations available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Gisgraphy**](http://www.gisgraphy.com/). The best services for your specific case are 
**reversegeocoding** or maybe the even better **geolocalisation**.
That's the page with the above [APIs](http://www.gisgraphy.com/documentation/api/) and it's well documented.
While this is the [UserGuide](http://www.gisgraphy.com/documentation/user-guide.htm) for specific info on the service that you will choose.

Comment: Thanks  Alex. Will have a look at your reference.

Answer (score 0):

The best IP geocode API that I've found is available from IPDATA.CO ([www.ipdata.com](http://www.ipdata.com)).  It's not free, but their rates are very reasonable, and it works really well.